# create asynctask class in java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and I'd like to create a java file that I can pass a path to and this java class returns the result list. The main goal is that I won't have to use this asynctask in 3-4 activity, because I can pass the argument to a class and get the result list in return.

How should I modify this script (deleting onCreate and so on)?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Aszin extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String USERNAME = "tom"; // username for remote host
private static String PASSWORD = "pass"; // password of the remote host
private static String host = "192.168.0.41"; // remote host address
private static int port = 22;

String cmd = "python /home/pi/Desktop/projects/ami/ami2.py ";
TextView tv1;
Button btn_ssh;
private AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> asyncTask;
ProgressBar bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aszin);

    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.kuki);
    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText("default");

    btn_ssh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn_ssh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            connect2pi(cmd);
        }
    });
}

public void connect2pi(final String cmd) {
    asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... Params) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                Session session = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, host, port);

                session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setPassword(PASSWORD);

                session.connect();

                ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

                InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

                channelExec.setCommand(cmd);
                channelExec.connect();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.add(line);

                }
                channelExec.getExitStatus();

                channelExec.disconnect();

                session.disconnect();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
            //tv1.setText("your file has been downloaded");
            Toast.makeText(Aszin.this, "your file has been downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Toast.makeText(FiveButtonActivity.this, "result: " + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            btn_ssh.setEnabled(true);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //tv1.setText("your file is getting downloaded");
            Toast.makeText(Aszin.this, "your file is getting downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            btn_ssh.setEnabled(false);
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute(cmd);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. One way would be to make your function `connect2pi` static and pass the views `bar` and `btn_ssh` as the parameters.
For Toast use `btn.ssh.getContext()` as the first parameter. Then you can call the static method from any class.

Comment: Cool! Thanks very much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can I pass from a random activity to this piConnector.java an argument? https://pastebin.com/j7CrzNXW

Comment: new piConnector().arg2pi("arg");

Comment: You're awesome, thans again!

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class that extend's AsyncTask.

```
public class ConnectPi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
         String cmd = params[0];
        // background code here
    }
};
```

And since in every activity there are different elements that you want to edit, you can use it like this:

```
ConnectPi connectPi = new ConnectPi(){
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        //tv1.setText("your file has been downloaded");
        Toast.makeText(Aszin.this, "your file has been downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Toast.makeText(FiveButtonActivity.this, "result: " + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        btn_ssh.setEnabled(true);
        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //tv1.setText("your file is getting downloaded");
        Toast.makeText(Aszin.this, "your file is getting downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        btn_ssh.setEnabled(false);
    }
    };
};
connectPi.execute(cmd);
```

For more information and examples about AsyncTask go to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems very helpful!

Comment: Oh! ok then. Thanks for trying

Comment: Sorry, I have a little problem here: how do I get the cmd string in the connectPi class, in the doInBackground method from this: connectPi.execute(cmd)? Thanks

Comment: @Marci now take look at doInBackground section